# C# for web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I am about to embark on what I would consider to be a rather large project, and I'd like to mark it by adding to my skillset. I already know PHP, Java, HTML, CSS and a bit of C.

I'd like to create my next web app using C#, but I'm not entirely sure if this is a good idea. Would doing this allow me a lot of flexibility? I assume that the prettifying the page would still be done using CSS, is this correct? If I choose to write in C#, will I still be able to add some client side processing, and would it still give me the level of flexibility I would have if I were to use javascript or php?

I've been looking at tutorials online and it's difficult to find what differentiates the use of C# from any other language, so that's really what I am getting at here. What are the particular caveats I should be aware of when beginning a project using C#? What are some good online resources for beginning to use the language?

Comment: This is a very broad and rambling question. We can't decide whether it's worth learning a given technology for you.

Comment: Why close as "not a real question". It's perfectly real, and quite specific. It just happens to be a question from a confused person.

Comment: @Inerdial: his real question revolves around him thinking that "C#" has anything to do with web development. He needs to look at asp.net.

Comment: Yes, I am confused. Sorry about that. I was hoping someone would be able to set me on the right path! :)

Comment: In all guides I have seen it has been a mix of ASP.NET and C#, is there no way of integrating the two together?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, "not a real question" includes "overly broad"

Comment: I need help solving my broad question before I can get to the more specific ones though! :)

Comment: @JohnSaunders I cast the close vote because the text of the question lists no less than five questions, four of which are in and of themselves bad SO questions. (That is: "Will this give me enough?" hinges on the definition of "flexibility", and on the definition of "enough", it's both vague and subjective. "What are particular caveats?" is a poll. "What are good online resources" is a reading material recommendation.) While pointing the OP at ASP.NET might be useful to him, I'd argue the question in its current form is confusing, and probably unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: @SimonKiely Your broad question would be best solved by hitting the .NET documentation and actually trying to code something in ASP.NET.

Comment: Doing so right now, Inerdial! Many thanks for the help everyone! I will hopefully come back with some more specific questions in time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place. Look for information on ASP.NET, not on C#. C# is just the programming language. ASP.NET is the Web Framework.

See http://asp.net.

An ASP.NET application may be created in either C# or VB.NET (maybe even F# now). Components used by the application may be created in any .NET language.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest ASP.NET MVC, http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Ditto. All the structure of a compiled application and great IDE support.

Answer (score 0):

if you can write php, then asp.net has the same role: to generate html. c# is just one of the lingos used to drive asp.net. yyou still use css and js to style and manipulate dom on client. you'll be worth more with asp.net on ur belt. it should be easier for you, since you won't have to stress about html, css and js, as u already know those.